# Django legacy db and foreign keys

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, foreign-keys, inspectdb

I'm working with a legacy mysql db with from a php project that is active so I can't change its schema, I've used `inspectdb` to create the models, now I want to add foreign keys to the models that aren't present , is there a way to do that without modifying the db?

For example: `inspectdb` gives me two models:

```
class OwaDocument(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    page_title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'owa_document'

class OwaReferer(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    site_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    site = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'owa_referer'
```

And I want to add a new field that doesn't exist, but without modifying my db

Comment: Please show some code to make it easier to understand your question.

Comment: What would be the values of the new fields if there's no underlying database column?

Comment: I don't know, they can be empty or Null, there's no problem with that, it is more a question in the air than a real life situation

Answer (score 0):

No, I think you need to modify the DB.